# How to avoid getting mixed outputs with QProcess->readAllStandardOutput()?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QProcess` in which I get data from the backend of my application. I have a simple connection to get the output `string` generated by `QProcess`. Right now it works well if I request a single command.

Now, I need to run two commands in a row one by one. The expected behavior is the following:

- Send command 1
- Wait for the output of command 1
- Store the output of command 1 in a variable
- Send command 2
- Wait for the output of command 2
- Store the output of command 2 in a variable

But I'm having an unexpected behavior. The two commands are sent to the backend, but `sometimes` I get a mixed output from the two outputs. I think it could be related to the time it takes for the backend to return the first result. I need to wait for the first output to send the second command. Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

If if use `study->waitForFinished();` or `study->waitForFinished(-1);` the app freezes and then crash.

This is my code:

```
connect(study, &QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput, [=] {
  QString out = study->readAllStandardOutput();
  qDebug()<< "Output= " << out;
}
```

```
void StudyClass::writeCommand(const QString& line) {
    study->write(line.toLocal8Bit());
}
```

If I write two commands as follows:

```
    writeCommand("print_status;");
    writeCommand("print_say_hello");
```

Sometimes I get the desired output (qDebug called in the connection):

```
    Output= 0
    Output= hello world
```

But sometimes I just get a mixed output:

```
    Output= 0 hello world
```

This is wrong behavior, because I need to get results for each command instead of just one.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have separate outputs for the two commands you have to wait for the first output and only then send the second command. You seem to send both commands without a delay and so occasionally you get the output of both commands in one call to the signal handler.

Comment: Yes, the question now is: how to add a delay between the two commands?

Comment: @BadRobot That seems like a new question. So you might want to accept this answer and open a new question for the problem of how to send the second command only when the first one has completed. Oh, and welcome to stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your QProcess is a long running process taking input commands through stdin, and then you want to capture the output of each of these commands. If that is the case, then calling `study->waitForFinished()` on the main thread blocks because the process is still running after each command.

Instead you could try `waitForReadyRead()` or `waitForBytesWritten()`.

Comment: Hi Joe, I already tried `waitForReadyRead()` but still get the same result. With `waitForBytesWritten()` my application freezes.

Comment: Does each command launch a new process, or is it a single process running in the background? I ask because if a new process is launched for each command, there is a function you can use to redirect the output into it's own file. Then there wouldn't be any possiblity of the command output overlapping.

Comment: It's a single QProcess running in the background.